# How to efficiently generate this dictionary by partitioning a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe `df` as follows

```
    parent_id   name
0   t3_35jfjt   t1_cr4y72v
1   t3_35jfjt   t1_cr4y7m7
2   t3_35jfjt   t1_cr4y7p3
3   t1_cr4y72v  t1_cr4y92z
4   t3_35jfjt   t1_cr4y986
... ...         ...
```

in which all elements in column `name` are unique. I would like to partition column `name` based on column `parent_id`. This means 2 elements in column `name` belong to the same class if they have the same `parent_id`.

Then I would like to create a dictionary whose keys are elements in column `name` and whose values are the number of elements of the class to which those elements belong. For example,

```
{'t1_cr4y72v': 3, 't1_cr4y72v': 4,...}
```

In this case, `t1_cr4y72v` belong to the class whose cardinality is 3.

I can use a loop to make this dictionary, but it's not efficient since I have over 3 millions rows. Could you please elaborate on an efficient method?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/WebMining/main/df.csv', header = 0)
df
```

Comment: @Manakin I've just tried your code and it returns 1 for every key of the dictionary.

Comment: @Manakin Assume that the corresponding `parent_id` of `t1_cr4y72v` is `xx`. Let G be the group of all elements in column `name` whose `parent_id` is `xx`. The the size of G is 3.

Comment: ah that makes sense, lots of ways you can do it, something like `pd.merge(df.set_index('name').drop('parent_id',1),df.groupby('parent_id')['parent_id'].size(),left_index=True,right_index=True,how='outer').to_dict()` should work

Comment: @Manakin So longgg :)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
dict(zip(df.name, df.groupby('parent_id')['parent_id'].transform('count')))
```

Comment: Hi @jlesuffleur, I hope you can shed some light on a faster method in my closely-related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66630243/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-children-for-each-element-in-a-column).

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```py
df.merge(
    df.groupby("parent_id")["name"].nunique().rename("cardinality"),
    on="parent_id"
).set_index("name")["cardinality"].to_dict()
```