# How to efficiently count the number of children for each element in a column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, group-by

I have a dataframe `df` as follows.

```
    parent_id   name
0   t3_35jfjt   t1_cr4y72v
1   t3_35jfjt   t1_cr4y7m7
2   t3_35jfjt   t1_cr4y7p3
3   t1_cr4y72v  t1_cr4y92z
4   t3_35jfjt   t1_cr4y986
... ...         ...
```

in which all elements in column `name` are unique. I would like to create a dictionary whose keys are elements from column `name`. For each such a key, we count its frequency on column `parent_id`. If it does not appear in column `parent_id`, then the value of such key is of course 0.

I do so as below, but it's not efficient since I have over 3 millions rows. Could you please elaborate on a more efficient method?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/WebMining/main/df.csv', header = 0)

# Create df2 to contain the counts
df2 = df.groupby(by = 'parent_id', as_index = False).size()

# Join df2 and df based on column "parent_id"
df3 = pd.merge(df, df2, how = 'left', left_on= 'name', right_on= 'parent_id')

# Replace NaN with 0
df4 = df3.fillna(0).rename(columns = {'size': 'num_siblings'})
df5 = df4[['name', 'num_siblings']]

# My expected dictionary
df5.set_index('name').T.to_dict('records')[0]
```

It is

```
{'t1_cr4y72v': 27.0,
 't1_cr4y7m7': 26.0,
 't1_cr4y7p3': 148.0,
 't1_cr4y92z': 0.0,
 't1_cr4y986': 43.0,
 't1_cr4ya0g': 11.0,
 't1_cr4yai8': 1.0,
....
```

Comment: can you shared expected output so we know what you are looking for. I think a transform should do the trick but would like to see expected results to give you a solution

Comment: I did a `len(pd.unique(df['name']))` and found `12718`. There are `12718` rows. So it looks like each row in `df` is a unique value of `name`. So if you want a dictionary, then it will have `12718` keys of `name` with count of 1. Is that what you want?

Comment: Alternate, we can do `{'t3_35jfjt':4}` to give you the count of `name` for each `parent_id`. Would that be a better solution? Again, once we know what your expected output is, we can solve for it

Comment: @JoeFerndz Please see my edit.

Comment: `df.groupby('parent_id').count().to_dict()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/WebMining/main/df.csv', header = 0)

# Create df2 to contain the counts
df2 = df.groupby(by = 'parent_id').size()

df2.reindex(df['name'], fill_value=0).to_dict()
```

Comment: Exactlyyy :)) Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Yup. I was going to recommend same thing.

Comment: That's fantastic and many thanks for you @JoeFerndz!

Comment: You can also give `d = df.groupby('parent_id').agg({'count'}).to_dict()`. I think you should get the same results